# Android ads google play services is missing

Tags: android, service, admob, ads

I recently tried adding admob ads into my android app,
Everything works fine on my emulator, ads are shown and no problems whatsoever.

However,
When i my app on my android device, i get this message in logcat:
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1424): Google Play services is missing.

And no ads are shown, whereas on my emulator ads are shown (test ads though).

I have included the google-play-services-lib into my project.

Thanks

Comment: you need updated version of google settings app in your mobile thats my guess

Comment: I have ran this on an emulator with 4.0.3 (which is the same version as my device) and it worked on there.

Comment: I meant an extra app called google settings in your device it has nothing to do with os version

Comment: How exactly would i update my settings app?

Answer (score 0):

Update your SDK with latest Google APIs. Create another emulator (or re-create existing one) with target Google API (for e.g. 19). It worked for me.

Comment: I am on the latest API and i have this problem on my device, not emulator.