# Sudden issue with Google Play Ads

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I've been working on a tile puzzle app for some time now.  Up until last week the ads portion worked just fine, but now every time I try to test on any emulator I get this:

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
>   W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

and it freezes the app.

As per the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) I've updated

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.4.0'

to

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'

Yet I'm still getting this error.  It doesn't seem to matter if the emulator in question has google apis or not.  Up till now my primary emulator for this project has been a nexus with API 18 without google play APIs.  Initially this was an intermittent issue, but now it won't work at all.  I've looked all over for a solution but I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Error "W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing."
　⇒ Please refer to the similar cases are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420435/admobs-banner-w-googleplayservicesutil-google-play-services-is-missing) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341581/android-ads-google-play-services-is-missing).

Comment: Error "W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0"
　⇒ Please refer to the similar cases are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198246/admob-android-giving-error-code-0) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198246/admob-android-giving-error-code-0).